# Exact Definition of Non-Isomorphic Posets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

This screenshot is from [Invitation to Discrete Mathematics by Matoušek.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198570422) :

[image]

I understand the definition when **two posets** (or ordered sets) are isomorphic or non-isomorphic. However, I am confused about question (a), the selected line in the screenshot.

More generally, when we talk about **Non-Isomorphic n-element posets**, do we mean that they are pair-wise non-isomorphic, or do we mean that for any of these posets, we cannot find another poset that is isomorphic to it (which would imply the previous I guess)?

Thanks!

Comment: They want you to give exactly one representative form each class of isomorphic 3-element posets. They should be pair-wise nonisomorphic, so that any $3$-element poset is isomorphic to one, and only one, of the 3-element posets you drew. Same if they were asking for $4$-element posets, $5$-element posets, or $n$-element posets.

Comment: Just draw all 3 element posets.

Comment: Here's a point to ponder: Is there such a thing as a poset which is not isomorphic to any other poset? If there is no such thing, that makes one of your proposed interpretations rather unlikely, doesn't it?

Comment: @bof Great point... Thanks!

Comment: Actually there is one: the empty poset is not isomorphic to anything alse. I don't know if that counts as a poset or not.  Anyway, every $3$-element poset is isomorphic to many others.

Comment: @bof: every poset is isomoprhic to itself, including the empty poset.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I thought I covered that with the word "other" in my first comment and "else" in my second comment. I guess my grasp of the English language isn't as good as I thought it was.

Comment: @bof: In mathematical usage, “any other” does not exclude the possibility of the same thing, just like “any two” does not exclude the possibility of picking the same thing twice. It’s a problem of potentially being ambiguous, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to draw $n$ many Hasse diagrams for posets $P_1, P_2, \ldots P_n$, all having $3$ elements, such that if $i \neq j$ then $P_i$ is *not* isomorphic to $P_j$ and moreover if $P$ is *any* three-element poset there is an $i\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ so that $P$ is isomorphic to $P_i$.

So you have then a "catalogue" of all "types" of posets of that size with a unique representative for all. Your job is to figure out $n$ and the $P_i$.